# ORA-00907 (missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run this in my database but for some reason, I keep getting missing the right parenthesis. Thoughts?

```
CREATE TABLE PET_OWNER
(
    OwnerID Int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    OwnerLastName Char(25) NOT NULL, 
    OwnerFirstName Char(25) NOT NULL, 
    OwnerPhone Char(12) NULL, 
    OwnerEmail VarChar(100) NULL
    CONSTRAINT OWNER_PK PRIMARY KEY(OwnerID) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

EShirvana's answer directly answers the question you asked.  However, I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE PET_OWNER (
    OwnerID Int generated always as identity primary key,  
    OwnerLastName varchar2(25) NOT NULL, 
    OwnerFirstName varchar2(25) NOT NULL, 
    OwnerPhone varchar2(12), 
    OwnerEmail varchar2(100)
);
```

The differences:

- The `primary key` constraint can be inlined.  To be honest, I don't generally see much use for naming the primary key as a separate constraint (no harm).
- Declaring a primary key column as `NOT NULL` is redundant.  That is part of being a primary key.
- Do you know what the `char()` data type does?  It pads strings with spaces so they match the length.  Use variable length strings -- and Oracle recommends `varchar2()` for this purpose.
- By default, columns are NULLable.  I actually find that explicitly declaring `NULL` is *harder* to read because I have to distinguish between `NOT NULL` and `NULL` which requires more work than just seeing `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:
identity and missing comma before constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE PET_OWNER(
    OwnerID Int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    OwnerLastName Char(25) NOT NULL,
    OwnerFirstName Char(25) NOT NULL,
    OwnerPhone Char(12) NULL,
    OwnerEmail VarChar(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT OWNER_PK PRIMARY KEY(OwnerID)
);
```